# css focus on a full table

Tags: css, hover, focus

I want to focus a full table when is selected, but when I click on the table focus is not working.

So I tried hover on the table and hover is working. How can I focus the whole table?

https://jsfiddle.net/bbe7x7bp/1/

```
table {
    border: 1px solid #e2e2e4;
    text-align: left;
}

table:hover {
    border: 3px solid #878b93;
    outline: 1px solid #242b3a;
}

.table:focus {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    outline: 1px solid darkblue;
}
```

Comment: `:focus` is for form inputs, not tables.

Comment: The `:focus` CSS pseudo-class is applied when an element has received focus, either from the user selecting it with the use of a keyboard or by activating with the mouse (e.g. a form input). Source: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Afocus)

Comment: @j08691 it's actually for *interactive elements*; if the `table` had the `contenteditable` attribute, for example, `:focus` would work on it just fine.

Comment: Then I will do it with jquery :(

Comment: @JamesDonnelly - thanks, I'm aware of that. I didn't bother to go into the finer points of :focus since the table in this case isn't being affected by the contenteditable attribute.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add **tabindex** to your table (in the HTML). Set **tabindex="0"** to put it in the natural tab order or **tabindex=-1** to make it focusable, but not something you can tab to. **tabindex=1** will force it to be the first thing in the tab order..

Just like here: https://jsfiddle.net/bbe7x7bp/2/

```
<table class="table" tabindex="1">
  <tbody>
  <trhead>
    <td colspan="7">Some title</td>
  </trhead>
    <tr class="table-info">
      <td>data 1</td>
      <td>data 2</td>
      <td colspan="5">data something</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

and

```
table {
  border: 1px solid #e2e2e4;
  text-align: left;
}

table:hover {
  border: 3px solid #878b93;
  outline: 1px solid #242b3a;
}

.table:focus {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  outline: 1px solid darkblue;
}
```

and you can read about tabindex right here: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_tabindex.asp

Comment: Nice! I wanted to post this jQuery solution: https://jsfiddle.net/damagex/bbe7x7bp/3/ - But yours is much better.

Answer (score 1):

`<a>`s, `<button>`s, `<input>`s, and textareas all have the :focus state by default, but you can give a focus state to any element in HTML5. Both the contenteditable and tabindex attributes work for this, as in this example:

```
<table contenteditable tabindex="1">  
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Option 1</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>    
    <tr>
      <td>Me</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

[Codepen here](http://codepen.io/str0kes/pen/LGWNYw)